# Do these conditions force $G$ to be a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a set $G=\{e,g,g'\}$ such that $e\circ{} g = g$ and $g\circ g'=e$ where $\circ$ is an associative operation. These conditions are seemingly weaker than outright stating $G$ is a group because both the identity and the inverses only work from one side. However, we should be able to show that these conditions force $G$ to be a group.

That is, using these conditions, we should be able to show that $g\circ e=g$ and $g'\circ g =e$.

I have gone round and round trying to get this to work with no avail. I'm pretty sure we can't use the cancellation property for groups since we haven't shown that $G$ is a group yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need something else, like associativity.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to mention associativity works. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If no further conditions are given, then you cannot prove that $G$ is a group because you've only given 2 entries in the multiplication table and you need 9.

If you assume that $\circ$ is associative, then you can deduce more. For instance:
$$
e \circ e = e\circ (g \circ g') = (e\circ g) \circ g' = g \circ g' = e
$$
which gives you 1 more entry in the table.

Associativity restricts the multiplication table but there's still lots of room. See for instance

- [Associative Operations on a Three-Element Set](http://www.math.umt.edu/tmme/vol5no2and3/TMME_vol5nos2and3_a8_pp.257_268.pdf)
- [How many binary operations are associative?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110211/how-many-binary-operations-are-associative)

Comment: O.O ... Thank you so much. I feel like a fool now.

Comment: Wait... that hasn't told us anything new though. We still don't have that $e\circ g = g\circ e=g$

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough (see comment of André and answer of lhf). In this context it is interesting to note that the following conditions are indeed enough for $G$ to be a group:

1) associative multiplication

2) existence of left-identity $e$ (i.e $eg=g$ for each $g$)

3) existence of left-inverse $g^{-1}$ for each $g$ (i.e. $g^{-1}g=e$ for each $g$)

If $x^2=x$ then it can be shown under these conditions that $x=e$. This by: $$x=ex=x^{-1}x^2=x^{-1}x=e$$ So from $gg^{-1}gg^{-1}=geg^{-1}=gg^{-1}$ it follows that $gg^{-1}=e$. This shows that $g^{-1}$ also works as a right-inverse. Then you have $ge=gg^{-1}g=eg=g$ showing that $e$ also works as right-identity.

If the word 'left' in 2) and 3) is replaced by 'right' then you also have sufficient conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I had made some huge mistakes here. The problem stated that for every $g\in G$ there exists some $g'\in G$ such that $gg'=e$. I mistakenly took this to mean that those were the only elements in $G$ (hey, it's late). But if I let $gg'=e$ and $g'g''=e$ then I can say

$g=g*e=g*(g'*g'')=(g*g')*g''=g'*g''=e$

$g'*g=g'*(e*g'')=(g'*e)*g''=g'*g''=e$

So we now have $g*g'=g'*g=e$ for all $g\in G$

Then

$e*g=(g*g')*g=g*(g'*g)=g*e=g$

Giving (finally!),

$g*e=e*g=g$.

Now it's a group.