# Condition to be a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a semigroup.

I'm showing that 
$G-group \iff [ \ \exists_{e\in G} \forall_{a\in G}: ea=a\ ] $ and $ [\ \forall_{a\in G}\exists_{a^{-1}\in G}: a^{-1}a=e \ ] $

"$\Rightarrow$" is obvious.

"$\Leftarrow$" This is how I do it:
Let $a \in G$.
 $ea=a$
$aea=aa$
$(ae)a=aa$
Is it true that this implies $ae=a$? How's that possible?

If the answer to my question is correct, then the  $ [\ \forall_{a\in G}\exists_{a^{-1}\in G}: a^{-1}a=e \ ] $
part is easy.

And will $G$ be a group if its a semigroup with left identity and right inverse?

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/653081/75923

Comment: I am too lazy to search for a counterexample, but the answer on your last question is: 'no, not necessarily'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is useful here to start by proving that $e$ is unique in satisfying $ee=e$. This by:

If $xx=x$  then $x=ex=x^{-1}xx=x^{-1}x=e$.

For $x=aa^{-1}$ we find: $xx=aa^{-1}aa^{-1}=aea^{-1}=aa^{-1}=x$ so are allowed to conclude that $aa^{-1}=e$. This proves that $a^{-1}$ also functions as a right inverse.

Then $ae=aa^{-1}a=ea=a$ so $e$ also functions as right identity.

This completes the proof.