# Counterexample to a weak "definition" of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Usually, we see a group as the structure $\langle G, \cdot\rangle$, where $G\neq\emptyset$ and the binary operation $\cdot$ is associative and

- $\exists e\in G,\,\forall a\in G,\,(a\cdot e=a=e\cdot a)$
- $\forall a\in G,\,\exists b\in G,\, (a\cdot b=e=b\cdot a)$

We can use a equivalent version of the definition,  where the operation is associative and

- $\exists e\in G,\,\forall a\in G,\, (a\cdot e=a)$
- $\forall a\in G,\,\exists b\in G,\, (a\cdot b=e)$

But, I read in Herstein's book that if we consider the operation associative and with the properties

- $\exists e\in G,\,\forall a\in G,\,(a\cdot e=a)$
- $\forall a\in G,\,\exists b\in G,\,(b\cdot a=e)$,

this is not equivalent to group definition.

My question is: which are examples of structures that satisfies those conditions and are not groups?

Comment: I'm guessing the 5th itemized formula should read $a \cdot e = a$.

Comment: Doesn't the first condition imply that $G$ has exactly one element? $e\cdot e=e=a$

Comment: The 5th formula should be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Take any set with at least two elements and define $a * b := a$.

Comment: Or in other words, consider for any set $X$ with two element or more the set of constant functions $X\rightarrow X$ with the composition operation.

Comment: But for any $a$ and $b$ in $G$, there exists an $e$ such that $e\cdot e=a$ and $e\cdot e=b$ so $a=b$ and hence $G$ has exactly one element.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that a multiplation on $G$ is associative.

If there is a right-identity $e$ with $ae=a$ for each $a$ and each
$a$ has a right-inverse $b$ with $ab=e$ for each $a$
then $G$ equipped with this multiplication is a group.

For a proof look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/653305/75923).

If there is a right-identity $e$ with $ae=a$ for each $a$ and each
$a$ has a left-inverse $b$ with $ba=e$ for each $a$
then $G$ equipped with this multiplication is **not necessarily** a group.
Let $G$ have exactly $2$ elements $e$ and $a$ and define $ee=e$,
$ea=e$, $ae=a$ and $aa=a$. It is routine to check that this multiplication
is associative. But with this multiplication $G$ is *not* a group.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy $ae=a$. Switch it.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. Done. Thanks.